# Finding documentation on python "native" types, e.g. set

Tags: python, set, splat

I'm trying to learn Python, and, while I managed to stumble on the answer to my current problem, I'd like to know how I can better find answers in the future.

My goal was to take a list of strings as input, and return a string whose characters were the union of the characters in the strings, e.g.

```
unionStrings( ("ab", "bc"))
```

would return "abc".

I implemented it like this:

```
def unionStrings( strings ):
     # Input: A list of strings
     # Output: A string that is the (set) union of input strings
    all = set()
    for s in strings:
         all = all.union(set(s))

    return "".join(sorted(list(all)))
```

I felt the for loop was unnecessary, and searched for more neater, more pythonic(?), improvements .

**First question**: I stumbled on using the class method `set.union()`, instead of `set1.union(set2)`. Should I have been able to find this in the standard Python docs?  I've not been able to find it there.

So I tried using set.union() like this:

```
>>> set.union( [set(x) for x in ("ab","bc")] )
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: descriptor 'union' requires a 'set' object but received a 'list'
```

Again, I stumbled around and finally found that I should be calling it like this:

```
>>> set.union( *[set(x) for x in ("ab","bc")] )
set(['a', 'c', 'b'])
```

**Second question**: I think this means that `set.union` is (effectively) declared as

```
set.union( *sets)
```

and not

```
set.union( setsList )
```

Is that correct? (I'm still learning how to use splat '*'.)

**Third question**: Where could I find documentation on the signature of `set.union()`? I didn't see it in the set/freezeset doc's, and I couldn't get the `inspect` module to give me anything. I'm not even sure `set` is a module, it seems to be a type. Is it defined in a module, or what?

Thanks for reading my complicated question. It's more "How do I navigate Python documentation?" than "How do I do this in Python code?".

---

Responding to jonrsharpe's comment:

Ohhhhh! I'm so used to C++ where you define separate static and instance methods. Now that you explain it I can really see what's happening.

The only thing I might do different is write it as

```
t = set.union( *[set(x) for x strings] )
return "".join(sorted(t))
```

because it bugs me to treat `strings[0]` differently from the strings in `strings[1:]` when, functionally, they don't play different roles. If I have to call `set()` on one of them, I'd rather call it on all of them, since `union()` is going to do it anyways. But that's just style, right?

Comment: Did you try: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset

Comment: Yes. I only saw the instance methods there, i.e. `set1.union(set2)`. That's why I wrote the ugly `for` loop version. Did I miss something there?

Comment: That's the same method, being called in a different way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several questions here. Firstly, you should know that:

```
Class.method(instance, arg)
```

is equivalent to:

```
instance.method(arg)
```

for *instance methods*. You can call the method on the class and explicitly provide the instance, or just call it on the instance.

For historical reasons, many of the standard library and built-in types don't follow the `UppercaseWords` convention for class names, but *they are classes*. Therefore

```
set.union(aset, anotherset)
```

is the same as

```
aset.union(anotherset)
```

`set` methods specifically can be tricky, because of the way they're often used. `set.method(arg1, arg2, ...)` requires `arg1` to *already be a `set`*, the instance for the method, but all the other arguments will be converted (from 2.6 on).

This isn't directly covered in the `set` docs, because it's true for everything; Python is pretty consistent.

In terms of needing to "splat", note that the docs say:

```
union(other, ...)
```

rather than

```
union(others)
```

i.e. each iterable is a separate argument, hence you need to unpack your list of iterables.

---

Your function could therefore be:

```
def union_strings(strings):
    if not strings:
        return ""
    return "".join(sorted(set(strings[0]).union(*strings[1:])))
```

or, avoiding the special-casing of `strings[0]`:

```
def union_strings(strings): 
    if not strings:
        return ""
    return "".join(sorted(set.union(*map(set, strings))))
```

Comment: Great answer. I added a longer response to the original question. Much thanks.

Comment: @Jonathan no problem; I've added a second implementation that might be more to your liking!

Comment: Ha ha! As I was writing my response I had though "I really just want to map `set` over my list of strings. I need to check out if/how `map()` works in Python?". Perfect answer!

Comment: No problem. Note that Python also supports static (no class or instance argument) and class methods (first argument is class `cls`) in classes, but this is just an alternative syntax for calling instance methods (first argument is instance `self`).